# Mongo 4.0.5 version isn't available in Mongo Site

Tags: mongodb

Sitecore 9.3 recommends to use mongo 4.0.5 version. But I cannot find the exact version on the mongo website (https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community)

Appreciate any help on this .

Answer (score 3):

You can download 4.0.5 version from here: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.5-signed.msi

I can see also 4.0.6-4.0.10 are compatible with Sitecore 9.3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @Vald's Answer, you can click on "Archived releases" from the available downloads or visit this URL - https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive, it will bring you to the archive page of the MongoDB release, you can select and download the required version you want to download from this page.

[image]